# File is automatically closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

```
f1 = open("D:/Studies/Python/IDEs/PyCharm/Basics/Basics.py", 'r')
print(next(f1))
```

The error is:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I'm trying to access this file from a program which is located in another path:-("D:\Studies\Python\IDEs\PyCharm\File IO\File_IO_Basics.py")

Is that a problem?

If there's any other problem please mention.

Comment: Is there a loop in your code where you closed this file or  check whether your file exists.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma no I didn't

Comment: Could you provide complete code, so that we could analyze the error.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your file has not been opened successfully. Try to include a `try ... except` near your open command and make sure that way that the file has really been opened:

```
try:
    f1 = open("D:/Studies/Python/IDEs/PyCharm/Basics/Basics.py", 'r')
    print "File has been opened"
    print(next(f1))
except:
    print "File has not been opened"
```

You could also check whether your file exists at that path using:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("C:\..."):   
    print "File exists"
```

Comment: When I check with os.path.exists...  there is the same error, (ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.) At the line "print 'File exists' "

Comment: That means that there is no file at the path you are looking for. I'd suggest that you start putting the file into the same directory as your program and remove the path. As soon as this works, you start to put it into a subdirectory, modify the path and see whether the code is successful. Only then do the full path. Most probably there is a problem with our path syntax.